# Use @JsonIgnore only for prodcution, but in tests it should be there

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, fasterxml

I have in Kotlin a (data) class like this.
While running the application with active Spring profile `live` I want to return only `name`.
But running the application with active Spring profile `test`, I want `version` to be shown, so I can test if I got the right version.

```
data class MyClass( 

 val name: String

 @JsonIgnore
 val version: Number

)
```

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you can use @JsonProperty and use a different json key to set the version. But your use case is not clear, provide some context why you need it.

Comment: https://uzxmx.github.io/add-or-remove-java-annotation-at-runtime.html etc; it's intrinsically non-trivial if the annotation itself doesn't support some form of run-time introspection. IIRC Jackson *does* provide some form of this via `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` (or at least did) but it may require modifying the object mapper code.

Comment: @RDK - use-case is: when I return the `MyClass` via REST I don't want the `version` to be shown.  But I need to verify, that it's the right version in my test. (longer story... that's the short version.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use different [Jackson JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) for test and prod env.

```
data class MyClass( 
 @JsonView(Views.Prod.class,Views.Test.class)
 val name: String

 @JsonView(Views.Test.class)
 val version: Number

)
```

And you have to manually take care of serialization/deserialization by passing the view based on environment.

```
MyClass class = mapper
      .readerWithView(Views.<Required-view>.class)
      .forType(MyClass.class)
      .readValue(json);
String result = mapper
      .writerWithView(Views.<Required-view>.class)
      .writeValueAsString(class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to only include it in the response if it's non-null. Then you could just create the object without a version number when you are running in production:

```
data class MyClass( 
    val name: String,

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    val version: Number? = null
)

// At creation:
val myClass = if (prod) MyClass(name) else MyClass(name, version)
```

Comment: (Leading to the possible issue that it's not that `version` isn't *used*, just that it's not visible when serializing.)